# How do I share a Paw extension privately

Tags: paw-app

I have created a Paw Extension that I want to share privately.

Is there a filename extension that I can use to share it, so users can double click to install (I.e. as a bundle).

Or do I have to share the extension directory and ask my users to put it into their extension container directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

What I would recommend is to make a private git repository with the code, containing an install script (a `Makefile` style script) that users can run to have the extension installed at the right place.

Here's an example: https://github.com/luckymarmot/Paw-RegexDynamicValue
There is a `Cakefile` that manages the build and the install at the right place. If you clone this repo, and run `cake install` you'll have the extension installed cleanly.

### Solution 2

As you said, it may be just easier to share a bundle (zip or tar archive) that users can manually open and drag to the right folder.
The extension folder can be easily found in Paw menu > Preferences > Extensions then hit "Open Extensions Directory".

Comment: I want to keep passwords and such out of git, and was hoping for just add '.paw-extension' to the directory, then Paw would to the copying for me.

Comment: Guess I'll just have to settle for #2.

Comment: Yeah, password handling isn't ideal for now. A better support with Keychain Access is to come in Paw 2.3!

Comment: 1Password support would also be nice!

Comment: Yeah that's a great idea :)